# Imagemagick cropping thumbnail command line

Tags: imagemagick, crop

I have an adult website and I want to remove watermarks by Imagemagick commands.
I would like to show you the thing I want as visuals.

Original image comes with 278x140 (I can change these) > [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX5XX.jpg)

What I want is something like this > [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnLq1.png)

In the default settings of ImageMagick in my website script, that command line is default;

```
-modulate 110,102,100 -sharpen 1x1 -enhance
```

and I added next to it `-gravity center -crop wxh+0+0` (I filled width and height in the code) but didn't work.

I just want my imagemagick command to crop a smaller square from the middle.

[This is my settings in the admin script of the website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S6Ph.jpg)

[After that, this is my screen of thumbnails in editing content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14NNk.jpg)

[When I click "regenarate", it doesn't give error, it says success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE575.jpg);

But nothing changes in the editing content screen after that. Still same thumbnails.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? What happened? Was there an error?

Comment: What is your version of Imagemagick and platform? Are you using Imagemagick Studio web interface? If so, from what URL are you accessing it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hey I've edited and added new screenshots to the post. You can check. There is no error.

Comment: @fmw42 Hey, I don't know it's exact version but, the script requires ImageMagick 6.7.7 or Higher.

Comment: `@Calvin Belfort`. Are you running Imagemagick in command line mode in a terminal or cmd window or are you using it from the Web via Imagemagick Studio. Some of your images look like you are using Imagemagick Studio. If so, the only authorized version is from http://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio. If you are using it from there and it does not work, then report that fact to https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=5. If you are still using -crop, then add +repage aftewards before saving the result.

Comment: @fmw42 I added also +repage in the command line but didn't work. I've added new screesnshots in the post. You will see my settings' page. I can also show the php codes of regenerating thumbnails if its needed.

Comment: `@Calvin Belfort` Where is this screen shot coming from --  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S6Ph.jpg? You never answered if you are using Imagemagick Studio and from what web site? If you are using PHP, then please show the full set of commands. Note that -sharpen 1x1 is not a very good command. Use -sharpen 0x1 and it will replace 0 with an appropriate value. Or use -unsharp. What were the values of WxH?

Comment: @fmw42 that screenshot is from the admin area of my tube website. [Pornstarlab](https://www.pornstarlab.com/) it's a nsfw website with one of the popular Mechbunny Script. I think Imagemagick is implemented into the script but I'm not sure if its using Imagemagick Studio or not. I don't know them that much. Original Image is 278x170 If I crop from the middle as 258x140 then it would be fine. This is the php file of when I click "regenarate thumbs" 
[First](https://i.imgur.com/fnQNLXU.jpg) and [Second](https://i.imgur.com/yB558K5.jpg)

Comment: `@Calvin Belfort` If you are not re-displaying the image after cropping, then the screen will not change. I am not sure where in your code you display the resulting image. Just running the Imagemagick command will not redisplay the image automatically. You need to do that your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Imagemagick 6.9.9.40 Q16 Mac OSX, I ran your command replacing 1x1 with 0x1 and it works just fine. I took your command from your code JPGs.

Input:

[image]

mogrify -modulate 110,102,100 -sharpen 0x1 -enhance -gravity center -crop 150x100+0+0 +repage OX5XX.jpg

I am not sure why you are using mogrify, if you are convert only one image at a time in your loop. You could just use convert as

```
convert OX5XX.jpg -modulate 110,102,100 -sharpen 0x1 -enhance -gravity center -crop 150x100+0+0 +repage OX5XX.jpg
```

[image]

I would suggest you make a simple PHP command to just run the same as above and see if that works. If it does, then the problem is in your other code and perhaps your usage of FFMPEG. If it does not work, then it could be a bug in your version of Imagemagick.

You can find out the version of Imagemagick by

```
<?php
exec("convert -version",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

If that fails, then find the full path to convert via

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("type -a convert");  
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for all the advices and help you made. It's now working with the code you gave! I also changed some codes on other php files about encoding Thank you!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider giving it an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete command it's hard to say exactly where the error might be, but with ImageMagick the first thing I'd try is the same command using "-extent wxh" instead of "-crop wxh+0+0" for this.

Comment: I've just updated and added new screenshots to the post. I also did as the way you told but didn't work tho.